# How to add an id for each test case in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

How can I add an ID for each test cases ( `it` ) in my script so that in my `jasmine-jsReporter.js` (my Jasmine reporter)? Can I access this ID and make appear on my report?

Thank You!

Comment: You'll need to clarify what "ID" means for each test case. Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can name your `it` functions in Jasmine just like any other javascript function

```
it("can be named like a normal function", function functionName() {
    //...
});
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: No, I was talking about inserting an ID in each `it`

Comment: Do you mean like an html ID or class?